# Integrate an application with GNOME search

Tags: 17.10, search, gnome-shell

I quite like the GNOME search. I would like to integrate another application that I use quite often, specifically geeknote, with the GNOME Dash search. How can I programmatically integrate this or another application, search?

For instance, when I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and I type something to search for, the Dash retrieves a list of result options, not just files or OS stuff. For example: Gnote notes.

Is there an API for this or something like that?

My Dash search example:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by integrate it with search? Does it not appear when you search for it? What is geeknote and how did you install it?

Comment: @Zanna I think OP was referring to the search result from geeknote's individual note appearing on gnome dash search.

Comment: for implementation advice this may be helpful: https://developer.gnome.org/SearchProvider/

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general answer. I suggest you to post the question to StackOverflow for more specific solutions.

Assuming that, you're referring to this [geeknote](https://github.com/VitaliyRodnenko/geeknote) which is an evernote client, you need to change the application to integrate with gnome dash search. The application is opensource so you can fork the repository and work on it.

As a help, you can look into [gnote](https://github.com/GNOME/gnote/tree/master/src)'s source code to see how things are implemented. Here is the overview page of the [Gnome Development guide](https://developer.gnome.org/platform-overview/unstable/).

But if you aren't a developer and looking for a solution from end-user's point, the best bet would be to create an issue with geeknote to request an implementation of the search. Other than this, I don't think there would be any third party plugin to help integrate geeknote with gnome dash.