# How to associate an AppImage to a mime type by default in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, appimage, platform-integration

I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338651/appimages-integration), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976784/integrate-an-application-with-gnome-search), [and this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342416/how-can-i-integrate-appimages-into-my-kubuntu-20-10-system).

Everyone talks about how to search for the app and launch it from a shortcut (instead of running it as an executable).

However, nobody talks about associating an AppImage with a mime type.

My goal is to click on a `.stl` file and open it with a default program that only ships as AppImage for Ubuntu/Linux.

As mentioned in the linked posts, this program already appears in the search because I *integrated* it by adding a `.desktop` launcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned that you've already looked at how to create a desktop launcher for your AppImage, I will skip that part.

You're looking to edit the `.desktop` launcher and change what mime types are associated with it.

*FWIW, this is not specifically for AppImages; this is how **freedesktop** desktop launchers work*

I don't know what program you're referring to, but I'll use the following launcher as an example.

The launcher below is for a text editor called Nota. We're interested in the line `MimeType=`; as you can see, it reads `MimeType=text/plain;` which means that Nota is associated with any text file.

```
[Desktop Action FirejailProfile]
Exec=firejail --env=DESKTOPINTEGRATION=appimaged --private --appimage /Applications/nota
Name=Run without sandbox profile
TryExec=firejail

[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Qt;KDE;Utility;TextEditor;
Comment[es_MX]=Text editor
Comment=Text editor
Exec=/home/uri/Applications/nota-v2.2.0-stable-amd64.AppImage
GenericName[es_MX]=Text Editor
GenericName=Text Editor
Icon=nota
Keywords=text;editor;
MimeType=text/plain;
Name[es_MX]=Nota
Name=Nota
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
TryExec=/Applications/nota
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

You can do the following to know what to put in that line for the desktop launcher you've created.

```
file -b --mime-type file.stl
```

This command will tell you what the mime type is. For example, the output could be `application/sla` for your `.stl` files.

So, the line in your desktop launcher would read `MimeType=application/sla;` so the desktop launcher would be registered to launch whatever is in `Exec=` and open that mime type.

---

Alternatively, you probably want to extract the upstream desktop launcher inside the AppImage and edit it accordingly, as I described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328529/4203).

---

Next, edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, and append:

`application/sla=YourApp.desktop;`